# TCL: Updating dict inside "dict with"

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I want to update the dictionary using dict with, but it does not seem to update any values. Example:

```
set test1 [dict create]
dict set test1 INST1 ports PORT1 type Q
dict set test1 INST1 ports PORT1 reset X
dict set test1 INST1 ports PORT2 type Qbar
dict set test1 INST1 ports PORT2 reset X

dict for {id data} $test1 {
    set resetVal 0
    dict with data {
        dict for {portName portInfo} $ports {        
            dict with portInfo {
                if {$type == "Q"} {
                    set reset $resetVal
                } elseif {$type == "Qbar"} {
                    set reset [expr $resetVal ^ 1]
                }
           }
       }
    }
}

puts "PORT1=[dict get $test1 INST1 ports PORT1 reset]"
puts "PORT2=[dict get $test1 INST1 ports PORT2 reset]"
```

It prints:

```
PORT1=X
PORT2=X
```

How can I update the value of "reset" using dict with?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can nest them like that. Try

```
set resetVal 0
foreach port {PORT1 PORT2} {
    dict with test1 INST1 ports $port {
        if {$type eq "Q"} {
            set reset $resetVal
        } elseif {$type eq "Qbar"} {
            set reset [expr {$resetVal ^ 1}]
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: You can nest them, but the effects might not be what you expect. `dict with` does not use variable linking (it works by copying things back at the end of the body) so some care is required.